# Breakpoint with inductor on schematic

Tags: inductor, schematics

I am designing a PCB and right now I am at the schematic stage.
I am trying to replicate the schematic of a voltage regulator IC.

This is from the datasheet.

[image]

I cannot undestand what is going on here and why the line "breaks" with `Vout` and why there are two `Vouts`. How am I supposed to design this?

Also, why the inductor has two lines above it? Is it a special kind or a typical inductor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "break" is the separation between the required and optional parts of the circuit.  Connect the arrow to the open circle next to the left "Vout" to add the optional filter.  The double line above the inductor symbol indicates an iron core, but I would read the datasheet closely to see what types the manufacturer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet gives you two options, either use the output directly from the capacitor C2, or add an optional LC filter after capacitor C2, so the output from the capacitor C3 is the one you use.

The two bars on inductor means it's an iron core inductor. That's more practical than say an air core inductor.